# Angular 14: Propagate FormArray with API response to use in select option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, formarray

I want to create several select option inputs with the response of an API.

I have defined this form with a **FormArray** input.

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  name: [null, [Validators.required]],
  details: this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
});
```

Then, the `getter` for the `detail` input as FormArray.

```js
get detailsArr() {
  return this.myForm.get('details') as FormArray;
}
```

I fetch data from a service and propagate the form values with the response. The response from the server for the `details` is something like this:

```js
"details": [
  { "detailName": "detail 1", "detailValue": 2},
  { "detailName": "detail 2", "detailValue": 4},
  { "detailName": "detail 3", "detailValue": 5}
]
```

```js
fetchData() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
    // Propagate details
    this.detailsArr.push(this.fb.control(res.details));

    // Propagate name
    this.myForm.patchValue({
      name: res.name,
    });
  });
}
```

The point is, I don't know *how to set the value of the details array to the details response*. With the `push` method I get an array inside an array, I mean:

```js
"details": [
  [
    { "detailName": "detail 1", "detailValue": 2}
  ]
]
```

The HTML is the following:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="details">
    <select *ngFor="let detail of detailsArr.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <option>{{ detail.detailName }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

I tried with `detailsArr.value` in the for loop and seems to work, but don't know why.

I just have followed [this Angular official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms), but doesn't work. I don' know if this is the correct approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution is the one posted by [@Youn Shun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8017690/yong-shun).**

I have just added some variables and inputs to control the **selected value**, but with this approach all works perfectly.

[Demo @StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvjqbz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  myForm: FormGroup;
  details: any[];
  detailSelected: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, [Validators.required]],
      detailSelected: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.details = res.details;

      this.myForm.patchValue({
        name: res.name,
        detailSelected: this.myForm.value.detailSelected,
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  Name: <input formControlName="name" />
  <label for="detailSelected">Detail:</label>
  <select id="detailSelected" formControlName="detailSelected">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let detail of details">
      <option [value]="detail.detailValue">{{ detail.detailName }}</option>
    </ng-container>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each element in the `details` array, you need to push it as `FormGroup` to `detailsArr` `FormArray`.

```
addDetailFormGroup(detail: any) {
  this.detailsArr.push(
    this.fb.group({
      detailName: detail.detailName,
      detailValue: detail.detailValue,
    })
  );
}
```

```
fetchData() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
    // Propagate details
    for (let detail of res.details) {
      this.addDetailFormGroup(detail);
    }

  ...
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkucdv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Updated**

As clarified with Post Owner, he wants to bind the data received from the API response as the options in the `<select>` element, the `FormArray` shouldn't be used in his scenario. `FormArray` is used when the form requires to render the element which contains multiple `FormControl` or `FormGroup`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It solves my *array inside array problem*. Anyway, my problem is with the `<select>` and `<option>` inputs. As you did in your demo, with `text` inputs works very well.

Comment: Hi, how is your `<select>` `<option>` look like? Does the formControl value match the value in `<option>`? Would be great if you can create a demo in StackBlitz.

Comment: Here is the demo: [Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2kv5fh?file=src/app/app.component.html). The `<select>` are there but I can't bind the data

Comment: Because your option is blank? Are you trying to render the `details` array as the options for `<select>` element?

Comment: If you try to render the `details` as option for `<select>` element, this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2p3lur?file=src/app/app.component.html) is what you need. And I don't think the formArray is needed here.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense and It was my first approach but I don't understand why not to use `FormArray`. I mean, why not to use the `details` key of the Form Builder and instead create a new property `details` for that purpose?

Comment: `FormArray` is used when you design the form that allows user to fill more than 1 item (can be either single or multiple FormControl). But the `details` array in the API response, is it the data that have been selected and you want to bind **as selected value** to the `<select>` element or is it the choices for the `<select>` element? That is why I confuse on what you try to achieve.

Comment: Exactly. I want to bind the API response data to propagate the `<select>` and also bind the selected value. I was wrong with the `FormArray` concep. Thanks again!